# Android Eddystone call to api when enter location on background

Tags: android, ionic-framework, eddystone

I am thinking on developing an eddyston beacon based app on ionic. I need to make sure that I can cover this situation:

1- The user has the phone in his pocket and the screen lock.

2- The phone gets on a beacon range.

3- As the user has my app installed he get a notification.

Giving the case that the user has the application installed, is it possible to make an api call once it enter the beacon area without unlocking the phone?

If its possible any suggestions to star looking around the way to do it?

Sorry for such a general question, I have looked everywhere if it is possible before asking the question. Sorry if it is a dump question and for my poor english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly possible to do what you describe with native code on Android, **it probably is not possible to make the API call from JavaScript using Ionic/Cordova.**

The trouble is that Ionic and Cordova rely on an Android `WebView` to host the JavaScript that would call the web service.  The `WebView` must reside inside an `Activity`, which is a native Android construct that hosts a visual screen.  Such a visual screen cannot be created without showing it, so there is no way to execute your JavaScript code to make the API call unless the screen is actually first shown to the user.

An alternative would be to make a hybrid app that uses a native component to detect the beacon and make the API call, and build the rest of your app using Ionic.  I have worked with other Ionic developers on precisely this solution.  If you go this route, I'd recommend using the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) to natively detect the Eddystone beacons even before the app is launched, and then trigger the notification from its native callbacks on beacon detection, and then make your API call.

It's worth noting that while there are also Ionic bindings for this library, they only work when the app is in the foreground.

Here's how you would set up code to make an API call when an Eddystone Beacon is detected using this library:

```
public class MyApplicationName extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
  private static final String TAG = "MyApplicationName";
  private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
     beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));

    // wake up the app when any beacon is seen (you can specify specific id filers in the parameters below)
    Region region = new Region("match-any-eddystone", null, null, null);
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
  }

  @Override
  public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
      // Don't care
  }

  @Override
  public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Got a didEnterRegion call");

    // TODO:  MAKE API CALL HERE

  }

  @Override
  public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {
    // Don't care
  }        
}
```

Full Disclosure:  I am lead developer on the Android Beacon Library Project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Just to confirm is possible then to fire up an API call without user interaction?? If that's the case I will go on on hybrid app or even just a native one

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely possible.  See my edited answer with example code.

Comment: Thanks .. great answer I'm working on this finally I decided to go with a native app.

Comment: Great!  There is some more setup code you have to do to get beacon detections working on Android.   Be sure to look at the quick start: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/configure.html and the requesting permission docs: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/requesting_permission.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions I will

Comment: @davidgyoung On an unrelated note, is the altbeacon library compatible with Eddystone beacons. I have used altbeacon on Android and iOS but with beacons which support altbeacon specs (which I felt is more or less similar to iBeacon protocol from Apple. Infact I read somewhere that the altbeacon specs itself came into being to support iBeacon like behaviour on Android). Would you suggest using Google Nearby Message API to detect Eddystone beacons or altbeacon lib. Does the altbeacon lib has any advantage over the Nearby api

Comment: Yes, the Android Beacon Library fully supports Eddystone.  There are several advantages of it over Google's Nearby and other APIs: it is much more flexible, it supports one second ranging updates, it is better documented and open source so there is less head-banging when it doesn't work.  Most importantly for many, it does not rely on Google Play Services so it works in China and on Amazon Fire devices whereas Nearby does not.  Finally, its APIs work similarly to those on  iOS so cross-platform apps are a breeze.